# "another", "an another" or "a another" which one is grammatically correct?

Tags: articles

Should I use "an" or "a" before the word "another"? If yes, when should use it. Or I can just use "another" without any of those articles(a/an).

Comment: _Another_ literally means _an other_, so it doesn't need a separate article.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the adjective **other**:

**Other** may be used *without an article*:

- **other** people
- **other** countries
- **other** languages

**Other** may be used *with a definite article*:

- the **other** day
- the **other** type
- the **other** problem

*But* - and this is the key point - **other** is **not used** with an indefinite article.

> We ***don't*** say or write:
>
> - an **other** pen
> - an **other** time
> - an **other** film

Instead, we say and write:

- **another** pen
- **another** time
- **another** film

Comment: So, we should not use or don't need to use "a"/"an" before "another"!

Comment: You're correct, @Rubel. It makes no more sense in English to say: _"an another [noun]"_ than it does to say: _"the the other [noun]"_.

Comment: Thanks for you kind support.